# running entire unit test in a loop

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'd like to be able to run the entire unit-test testSuite in 5 times in a row. This includes the start up, test, as well as a tear down methods.

I've tried everything under the sun, including adding the entire class into a for loop, but had no luck. Thanks for the help.

```
import unittest, time, re

class IIIAppforloop(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
           print("setting up")

    def testappforloop(self):
        print ("testappforloop1")
    def testappforloop2(self):
        print ("testappforloop2")

    def tearDown(self):
        print ("tearing down")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I fear you may be doing unit testing wrong.

Comment: If you're doing performance testing, this isn't the right approach.  If your unit tests have side effects or make persistent changes, this isn't the right approach either.

Comment: I'm helping our dev team discover random slowness on our site's order form by repeatedly running a Selenium script (for one user) until the slowness happens. reclosedev your answer was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to run tests in a loop and you are on Python 2.7+:

```
# ... skipped ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(5):
        unittest.main(exit=False)
```

Comment: This answer no longer works in Python 3.9. The test runs only once.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do stress testing with unittest-based tests, take a look at [FunkLoad](http://funkload.nuxeo.org/), it's designed for just that.

Otherwise, you will need a modified test runner.  You can find code in the standard library, unittest module, for the current test runner.  Likely you can instantiate an existing one and run it five times, like @reclosedev's answer.